# How to create a new blank empty area?

Tags: python, node-editor, 3d-view, interface, viewlayers

[image]

I would like to remove the area, yet leave the screen itself(red box) and create a whole **new empty black area**(light blue area) in that screen for making my own editor type. I've looking for awhile in the console but there's no options for turning off nor deleting the space itself.

Are there any ways to resolve this problem?

A sample code block;

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Screen, Area, NodeTree

area = bpy.context.screen.areas[2] # 'NODE_EDITOR'


if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR':
    node = area.spaces[0]
    view = area.spaces[1]
    outliner = area.spaces[2]
    
    node.show_region_ui = False
    view.show_region_ui = False
    outliner.display_mode = 'SCENES'
```

Another code block here. This one is `VIEW_3D` area but there's no options there neither;

```
area = bpy.context.screen.areas[4] # VIEW_3D


if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
    space = area.spaces[0]
    
    space.show_region_header = False
    space.show_region_hud = False
    space.show_object_viewport_mesh = False
    space.show_region_toolbar = False
    space.show_region_ui = False
    space.overlay.show_overlays = False # Hiding Grid on the floor

# ============== Initialize ==============
# ========================================
```

Comment: It's not possible to define custom editor types using the python API. You can only define new node editor types.

Comment: This is unrelated but FYI you can unpack variables in python like `node, area, outliner = area.spaces` rather than assigning them via indexing.